# Jquery $(window).on("load"... and chrome extensions

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension, I need to add a few listeners and classes to elements when my popup load.

So far, I've did this :

```
$("body").ready(main());
```

where I added things to the elements in my main function, problem is, elements doesn't exist when main is run, so it doesn't work.

I've looked and found that $(window).load() should be used. I tried, but got jquery errors. I've looked and found that $(window).on("load",main()) should work instead. I tried, and it "worked" just like my $("body").ready(...
For some ready, even the "window on load" thing doesn't wait for my elements to be fully loaded.
Simple test I'm trying to do is :

```
function main(){
    console.log($("#toto").attr("id"));
}
```

When I open the popup of my extension, it returns "undefined" in the console, but if I paste the same code, it returns "toto". 
How could I make this work please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's weird but I solved it like that :

```
window.onload=function(){
    main();
}
```

while $(window).load(... or $(window).on("load"... didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
var id = $("#toto").attr("id");
console.log(id);
});
```

you can use a separate function if you want but you have to define the function first:

```
function main(){
    console.log($("#toto").attr("id"));
}
$(document).ready(main());
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have my function defined.
I tried with document ready, but no success, also tried using a var instead of directly putting it into my console.log, but didn't worked either.
Also tried document load just in case, but nothing.

Comment: The var was not for solving the problem but for ease of use. this code works  in my browser, so i think the problem may be esewhere. you should give more details in order to find a sollution

Comment: I think the problem come from the fact that I'm not in a regular webpage, but in a chrome extension popup. My "load", or "ready" is supposed to be called when I open my extension's popup and it's fully loaded (on a clic on the extensions icon for exemple)

Comment: it may be. you should look for some chrome documentation on this